# Change Android applicationIdSuffix for release type

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My app has 4 flavors and each one sets its own `applicatioIdSuffix`. I also have 4 build types.

```
     flavorA {
        ...
        applicationIdSuffix '.flavorA'
    }
     flavorB {
        ...
        applicationIdSuffix '.flavorB'
    }
    flavorC {
        ...
        applicationIdSuffix '.flavorC'
    }
    flavorD {
        ...
        applicationIdSuffix '.flavorD'
    }

buildTypes {
    debug {
       .....
    }

    release {
       .....
    }

    debugClient {
       .....
    }

    releaseClient {
       .....
    }
}
```

Now, when I'm building the `releaseClient` version I want to override the `applicationIdSuffix` setting so that no suffix is added. I've tried to do:

```
releaseClient {
       applicationIdSuffix ''
}
```

Hopping that it would override the suffix set with the flavor but this does not work.

How can I change, for a specific build type, the `applicationIdSuffix` set by the flavor?

Comment: Nop, applicationIdSuffix just add some suffix and not replace. Why do you want some flavor suffix and then remove it ?

Comment: Thanks. Because that suffix must be added to the other 3 build types.

Comment: can you accept the answer if it's good ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of add `applicationIdSuffix` on flavors you can do this on `buildTypes {}`

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        release {
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
                    
                    applicationIdSuffix getFlavor(flavor)
                }
            }
        }
    }




def getFlavor(String flavor) {
   val suffix = ""

    if (flavor == "A")
       suffix = ".flavorA"
    ...

    return suffix
}
```